# Can Bootstrap be used to design a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I know the use of bootstrap in web design, I thought of creating a React Native app

Is it possible to create a React Native app using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use bootstrap or react-bootstrap in your react-native app.

If you want to use a component library, you can use Native Base ([native base](https://nativebase.io)) for your project. It's a component library and it'll help you to build UI easily.